# Python 'tkinter.BooleanVar' is not update

Tags: python, checkbox

I think 'var_empty' is not saved Checkbutton's status.
How to get vallue of Checkbutton?
When I checked, var_empty is 0 in all instance.

```
class contmanage_class():   #계약관리
    contlist_dict={}
    
    class cont_room():   #세대별 요금
        def __init__(self,page,room_num) -> None:
            self.page=page
            self.room_num=room_num

        def show_cont(self):
            self.frame=tkinter.Frame(self.page,relief='sunken',borderwidth=3)
            self.frame.pack(fill="both")
            self.button_room=tkinter.Button(self.frame, text=self.room_num+"호")
            self.button_room.pack(side=LEFT)
            self.var_empty = tkinter.BooleanVar()
            self.check_empty=tkinter.Checkbutton(self.frame, variable=self.var_empty, text="공실", bg='#a3d278', onvalue=True,offvalue=False)
            self.check_empty.pack(side=LEFT)
                  
        
        def save(self):
            print(id(self.var_empty))
            sql.connection().room_update(self.var_empty.get())
            self.load()

    def contmanage_popup(self):
        self.contmanage=Tk()
        self.contmanage.title("계약정보관리")
        self.contmanage.geometry("850x550")
        
        for room_num in room_num_list:
            self.contlist_dict[room_num]=self.cont_room(self.contmanage,str(room_num))
            self.contlist_dict[room_num].show_cont()

        self.load_all()
```

Comment: Does your program have more than one call to `Tk()`?  That tends to cause Vars to not work right - because they're associated with one particular instance of `Tk`, and will not work with widgets associated with a different instance.  (Use `Toplevel()` instead if your program needs additional windows.)

Comment: Yes, My program have more popup page